# Concatenating strings on Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm using the Javascript console on Google Earth Engine, and I'm stumped by a simple problem.  I want to concatenate and print two values on one line.  One of them is an object property.

When I use a comma to separate the parts in the print statement, I get the output I want, except that it is printed on separate lines.  When I use a plus ('+'), the object's `toString` method is invoked and I get vastly more output than I want.

```js
var img = ee.Image(img_list.get(0)) //grab an image
var date_index = img.get('system:index'); //get its date index property

print('MOD13Q_', date_index);
//Output (basically what I want, except on two lines instead of one)
//'MOD13Q_'
//'2018-01-17' 


print('MOD13Q_' + date_index); //Oops, '+' invoked the toString method
//'MOD13Q_ComputedObject({
  "type": "Invocation",
  "arguments": {
    "object": {
      "type": "Invocation",
      "arguments": {
        "list": {
          "type"....etc.
```

Is there any way to override the `toString` method, or to prevent it from being invoked?  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33339688/why-comma-and-plus-log-the-console-output-in-different-pattern) describes something similar, but does not show how to solve my problem.

Comment: The first print works because `print(date_index)` (where date_index is an ee Object) is a shortcut of print(date_index.getInfo()). You can still use your second print statement using the + operator, but you have to use .getInfo(): `print('MOD13Q_'+date_index.getInfo())`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use server-side string method `cat` instead of JavaScript concatenation operator `+`.

```
var outStr = ee.String('MOD13Q_').cat(date_index);
print(outStr);

// OUT: 'MOD13Q_2018-01-17'
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!  Does that work because the ee.Image `toString` method gets called when evaluating`get(property)` on the client side, whereas on the server side the `get(property)` method just returns the property directly?

Comment: I have no idea.